# Efficient update to rational flow network?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, network-flow

Once we've computed the max flow in a flow network with integral capacities, we can change one of its edges' capacity by a unit and recompute a maxflow in linear time using BFS. Is there something similar for rational networks where we might change a capacity by an arbitrary amount, or delete edges (which amounts to setting their capacities to 0)?

Comment: Have you tried something? What happens with the BFS solution?

Comment: @Raphael In the integral network, changing one edge capacity by 1 works with a BFS update because all you have to do is check whether there is one augmenting path in the residual network. That won't work with rational changes or in rational networks, since augmenting paths now may only provide partial compensation since the bottleneck on any path may be just a fraction of the difference by which we change capacities.